# Google App engine Add defer to backend

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have to perform some long tasks within a function that is called in 
    defered.defer().

i have added backend settings to backend.yaml. How can i run this defer on backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `target` parameter to make a [push task execute on backend](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#Python_Push_queues_and_backends).

Comment: This part of the doc might be pre-modules. See how to address backends now that modules are enabled: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing

Comment: Also relevant - how to convert backend to modules: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/converting

Comment: its working on local server fine but when deployed on app engine it just do nothing, gives no error and neither the queue is executed

Comment: Try calling the target url on backend directly, to check the config.